# On Drop-Down Select, store value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a registration form, to store family details in database table. I have my drop-down list of the number of brothers or sisters field.

```
<select id="purpose" required="required" name="purpose">
<option value="0">No Brother nor Sister</option>
<option value="1">Brother or/and Sister</option>
```

I would like to know on select of first option how to allocate null values for bro and sis fields in database.
The options with value 1 has got further additional fields that is is brother married or sister married. But if no bro nor sis exist then it should wrap at first stage only indicating bro and sis as null, followed by all further fields being null, like bro_married and sis_married.

My main form code :

```
<select id="purpose" required="required" name="purpose">
<option value="0">No Brother nor Sister</option>
<option value="1">Brother or/and Sister</option>
</select>

<div style='display:none;' id='business'>
<div>
<label for="username" class="uname">Number of Brothers</label>
<select id="bro" name="bro" required="required">
<option value="<?php if(isset($_GET['bro']))
{echo $_GET['bro'];}else{echo "";}?>"><?php if(isset($_GET['bro']))
{echo $_GET['bro'];}else{echo "Select";}?>
</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>                                                
</select>
</div>
```

My PHP file to save

```
if(isset($_POST['step_four_save']))
{
$bro=$_POST['bro'];
update_user_info=mysql_query("update partners_registration set bro='$bro' where email_username='$username' ");
```

Kindly advise, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I can understand this part: "if it is null or not chosen, so that it can be saved in the database" but `value=""` will provide an empty value

Comment: Yes, the scenario is, if brother or sister exist then input their details, if not then store in database zero values for bro or sis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure why you need to check the null for your dropdown. Dropdown will have at least blank '' or some value of first child (option) if you do not select any value on form submit.

Here is the code if you are looking for them:

```
if("" == trim($_POST['bro'])){
    //
}
```

Or

```
if (is_null($_POST['bro'])){
    //
}
```

Comment: Actually in the registration process, I need to check if bro or sis exist, if no then zero should be stored in the database, if yes then, is bro/sis married. Accordingly i need keep adding, so wherever it is NO then zero has to be stored in the database. Kindly advise, thanks.

Comment: Please set 0 for default top option, you can set the label for that option like "Please select sibling". Therefore, if you don't select it will remain 0 and post value will have 0 to save it db. If 0 is in the post value, you don't need to save other values like married.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bro column in partners_registration is integer then following code can work

```
if(isset($_POST['step_four_save']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['bro']) && $_POST['bro'] != "") {
        $bro = $_POST['bro'];       
    } else {
        $bro = NULL;
    }

    $update_user_info=mysql_query("update partners_registration set bro=$bro where email_username='$username' ");
}
```